Marshall Major IV Connection Issue
I'm new to ubuntu and I ran into this problem. I have dual boot ubuntu and windows on my computer and I use the same Marshall Major IV headphones. The problem is that after using the headphones on windows, in ubuntu you need to delete them in the settings and reconnect them again. The same works in reverse. Is there any way to solve this problem so that when changing the system, the headphones do not have to be reconnected? I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

[edit] your question with details of the distro/version of Ubuntu you are using
